# Counting lower case letters in a string and printing out their occurrence in the form of a histogram?

Tags: java, arrays, string, character

I am currently trying to write a program where the user will input a string and then the program will output the occurrence of lowercase letters as such:

```
"Hello world! The quick brown fox jumps over the fence."

a:
b:*
c:** 
d:*
e:*****
f:**
g:
h:***
... so on until z.
```

I just have no idea how to go about writing this. I've looked around but no one uses arrays. I was thinking you have an array for the alphabet and then have a loop that takes each element of the string and corresponds it with a letter of the alphabet, which then adds one to the counter which wil ultimately display the histogram.

Just not sure how to go about it.

Thanks.

EDIT: Here's what I have so far. It's not much and I still don't really understand what to do. But it's something.

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class CountingChars {


  public static void main(String[] args) { 
    System.out.println("Enter the text you would like to count the characters of. Please end with     a blank line.");
    Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
    String userInput = sc.nextLine();
    String alphabet = "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz";

    int[] amount = new int[alphabet.length()];

    //for (int i = 0; i < userInput.length();i++){
    //}
    char occurrence;
    int count = 0;

    while(userInput.length()>0){
      occurrence = userInput.charAt(0);
      int i = 0;

      while(i < userInput.length() && userInput.charAt(i) == occurrence){
       count++;
      }
    }


  }



}
```

Comment: You are on the right track. It can be done with array if you will use position of character in Unicode (assuming you want to focus only on letters) but such histogram can also be done (probably even easier) with Map. Unfortunately I am not going to post you code but if you will post your attempts I can try to explain your mistakes.

Comment: Use some kind of map or maybe multiset?

Answer (score 0):

Two basic ways of doing this which come to mind.

First is using an array of fixed length with stored ints (lower alph chars), where 'a' is on index 0. And then iterate through the given chararray updating the specific index (you can get the index by something like 'selectedChar' - 'a', which will give you the index position). Then you simply iterate through the list a print number of asterisks accordingly.

Second way is using a HashMap, where you store per each character the value, count the chars, update the value in the map accordingly and then simply go through the map and print those out (now that I am thinking about it, SortedMap will be better).

Answer (score -1):

```
 public static void printAlphabetHistogram(String input) {
        int amount[] = new int[25];
        for(char c : input.toCharArray()) {
            if(Character.isAlphabetic(c)) {
                c = Character.toLowerCase(c);
                amount[c - 'a'] += 1;
            }
        }
        for(int i = 0; i < amount.length; i++) {
            System.out.printf("%s:", (char)('a' + i));
            for(int j = 0; j < amount[i]; j++) {
                System.out.print("*");
            }
            System.out.println();
        }
 }
```

Comment: And that is how homeworks are solved these days. Don't give a fish but teach how to fish.

Comment: If he uses this for his homework, go ahead. The person will fail for his class and money will be wasted. If the person decides to see what I did, he might learn something of it